# Does the norm exist on $\mathscr S' \subset \mathscr D'$?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I take an extension from $L^2(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathscr S'(\mathbb R)$ of tempered distributions for a mapping of nonlinear distribution. 
I do not want to use seminorm, but the norm, therefore the extension to $\mathscr S'(\mathbb R)$.
$\mathscr S'(\mathbb R)$ is defined as the continuous dual of the Schwartz space, also $\mathscr S'(\mathbb R) \subset \mathscr D'(\mathbb R)$.

**Does the norm exist on $\mathscr S'(\mathbb R)$?**

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that it is difficult to show that the norm exists in $L^2(R)$"?

Comment: @gerw I removed the sentence because it is not necessary piece of information here.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking if there is a norm on $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R)$ which induces its usual topology?  The answer is going to be no because every open set of $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R)$ contains a line.

Comment: $\mathscr S'(\mathbf R)$ is a strong topology. I am not sure if your answer is right.

Comment: As was already explained to you, the strong topology on $\mathscr{S}'$ is not induced by a metric, so in particular there is no norm inducing the topology.

Comment: @Vobo I added better explanation now about the duality.